# How can I configure Apache Zookeeper with redundancy on only two physical frames?

Tags: apache, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I would like to have a high-availability/redundant installation of Zookeeper running in my production environment.  The problem is that I only have 2 physical frames available, so that rules out configuring a Zookeeper cluster/ensemble since I'd only have redundancy if the frame with the minority of servers goes down.  What is the best practice in this situation?  Is it possible to have a separate standalone install running on each frame connected to the same set of SOLR nodes or to use one server as primary and one as backup?

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper requires 3 nodes. In your scenario if you cannot get another machine you can setup multiple zookeeper nodes on the same machine in different directories using different ports.